# How can I include static data in script which uses $group instead of $project?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to add static data into a document which is like metadata in the header of the document that I will use to query later.

I can do this easily for a script which uses $project by including values using the $literal operator like:

```
db.std_sourceBusinessData.aggregate(
            { $unwind: "$accountBalances" },
            { $match: {"accountBalances": "Sales"}},
{ $project: {_id: 0,objectClass: {$literal: "Service Data"}, accountBalances: 1}}
//      , {$out : "entity_datapoints"}
)
```

But I need to do this for documents which uses $group instead. How would I add in "objectClass" : "Account Balances" as a static data input into the following script?

```
db.raw_originBusinessData.aggregate([
{ "$match": {objectOriginAPI : "Balance Sheet"}}
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports" }
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows" }
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows" }
,{ "$group": {"_id": "$_id","accountBalances": { "$push": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows.Cells.Value" }
}},
])
```

Thanks, Matt

Comment: so why does this get a negative one without even a reply? I think it's quite a simple question, thanks for the opinion with no help whatsoever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in that case, I will answer my own question from an answer graciously provided by another forum.

```
db.raw_originBusinessData.aggregate([
{ "$match": {objectOriginAPI : "Balance Sheet"}}
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports" }
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows" }
,{ "$unwind": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows" }
,{ "$group": {"_id": "$_id","accountBalances": { "$push": "$objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows.Cells.Value" }
}},
{$project: {objectClass: {$literal: "Account Balances"},accountBalances: "$accountBalances"}}
])
```

Can't believe some people man, I am pretty sure I asked a dumb question but I constructed it to the rules, all I wanted was someone to humour me and give me an answer not just hit the negative button and move on.